# Get selected value of a dropdown's item using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I get the selected value of a dropdown box using jQuery?
I tried using

```
var value = $('#dropDownId').val();
```

and

```
var value = $('select#dropDownId option:selected').val();
```

but both return an empty string.

Comment: Both of those should work. The problem must be somewhere else (e.g. is that code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(...` block?)

Comment: `var value = $('#dropDownId:selected').val();`

Comment: Nope - `$('#dropDownId').val();` is the most concise way to get the selected value.

Comment: @shyam you don't need select in this statement since IDs are unique for document, you should use tag name only when refering to classes`select#dropDownId option:selected`,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Index of select->option tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817079/how-to-get-the-index-of-select-option-tag)

Comment: Refer this article : http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery/

Comment: One can refer this article: http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery/

Answer (score 948, accepted):

For single select dom elements, to get the currently selected value:

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

To get the currently selected text:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

Comment: You need a space before `:selected`.

Comment: the **fastest** way of getting the text of the selected option is: `$("#dropDownId").children("option").filter(":selected").text()`

Comment: i wish you had linked references to `.val()` and `.text()`

Comment: Richard, your code is too long...it can be much more concise for readability

Comment: and how to know which index is selecteD?

Comment: In Share Point 2010 where id gets renamed, this works. $("[id$='dropDownId']").val()   and $("[id$='dropDownId']").children("option").filter(":selected").text()  thanks RickardN

Comment: What if you don't know the id of the `<select>`, and you only have a DOM reference to it?

Comment: @JamesM.Lay a DOM reference stored in a variable? Then use ``jQuery(domVariable).val()``

Comment: http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery/

Comment: @RickardN 's comment here should have been the accepted answer!!! It's the only thing that's worked for me.

Comment: argument type string is not assignable to parameter type for @RickardN 's answer

Comment: also what is a "single select dom element"?  Do you mean the one and only select element in a DOM that happens to be selected?

Answer (score 62):

```
var value = $('#dropDownId:selected').text()
```

Should work fine, see this example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#button1').click(function(){ 
    alert($('#combo :selected').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="combo">
  <option value="1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click!" />
```

Comment: "value" is what most coders miss, while declaring elementsand query keeps on returning text instead

Answer (score 27):

Try this jQuery,

```
$("#ddlid option:selected").text();
```

or this javascript,

```
 var selID=document.getElementById("ddlid");
 var text=selID.options[selID.selectedIndex].text;
```

If you need to access the value and not the text then try using `val()` method instead of `text()`.

Check out the below fiddle links.

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/8jPXb/) | [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/BwJeR/)

Answer (score 15):

try this

```
$("#yourDropdown option:selected").text();
```

Comment: OP is asking for selected value.  This answer would get the text content of the drop down. Not wrong, just not what he was asking for.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a terribly old post and I should probably be flogged for this pitiful resurrection, but I thought I would share a couple of VERY helpful little JS snippets that I use throughout every application in my arsenal...

If typing out:

```
$("#selector option:selected").val() // or
$("#selector option:selected").text()
```

is getting old, try adding these little crumpets to your global `*.js` file:

```
function soval(a) {
    return $('option:selected', a).val();
}
function sotext(a) {
    return $('option:selected', a).text();
}
```

and just write `soval("#selector");` or `sotext("#selector");` instead! Get even fancier by combining the two and returning an object containing both the `value` and the `text`!

```
function so(a) {
    my.value = $('option:selected', a).val();
    my.text  = $('option:selected', a).text();
    return my;
}
```

It saves me a ton of precious time, especially on form-heavy applications!

Answer (score 9):

This will alert the selected value.
JQuery Code...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myDropDown").change(function (event) {
            alert("You have Selected  :: "+$(this).val());
        });
    });
```

HTML Code...

```
<select id="myDropDown">
        <option>Milk</option>
        <option>Egg</option>
        <option>Bread</option>
        <option>Fruits</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 8):

this will do the trick

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

Answer (score 8):

Yet another tested example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#bonus').change(function() {
    alert($("#bonus option:selected").text());
  });  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="bonus">
<option value="1">-$5000</option>
<option value="2">-$2500</option>
<option value="3">$0</option>
<option value="4">$1</option>
<option value="5">We really appreciate your work</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it gets the value:

`$('select#myField').find('option:selected').val();`

Answer (score 5):

```js
function fundrp(){
    var text_value = $("#drpboxid option:selected").text();  
    console.log(text_value);
    var val_text = $("#drpboxid option:selected").val();  
    console.log(val_text);
    var value_text = $("#drpboxid option:selected").attr("value") ;
    console.log(value_text);
    var get_att_value = $("#drpboxid option:selected").attr("id") 
    console.log(get_att_value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drpboxid">
    <option id="1_one" value="one">one</option>
    <option id="2_two" value="two">two</option>
    <option id="3_three" value="three">three</option>              
</select>
<button id="btndrp" onclick="fundrp()">Tracking Report1234</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you supply your select-element with an id?

```
<select id='dropDownId'> ...
```

Your first statement should work!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
$('#dropDownId').find('option:selected').val()
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 3):

For selected text use:

```
value: $('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

For selected value use:

```
value: $('#dropDownId').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `id` that got generated for your drop down control in the `html` will be dynamic one. So use the complete id `$('ct100_<Your control id>').val().` It will work.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I though I update this with an more up to date answer

```
$( document ).on( 'change', '#combo', function () {
var prepMin= $("#combo option:selected").val();
 alert(prepMin);
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Or if you would try :

```
$("#foo").find("select[name=bar]").val();
```

I used It today and It working fine.

Answer (score 2):

To get the jquery value from drop down you just use below function just sent `id` and get the selected value:

```
function getValue(id){
    var value = "";
    if($('#'+id)[0]!=undefined && $('#'+id)[0]!=null){
        for(var i=0;i<$('#'+id)[0].length;i++){
            if($('#'+id)[0][i].selected == true){
                if(value != ""){
                    value = value + ", ";
                }
                value = value + $('#'+id)[0][i].innerText;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $('#dropDownId option').filter(':selected').text();     

 $('#dropDownId option').filter(':selected').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using following code.

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

If you want to get the selected value from the select list`s options. This will do the trick.

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select[id$=dropDownId]").val()
```

- try this

Answer (score 1):

use either of these codes

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

OR

```
$('#dropDownId').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#selector <b>></b> option:selected").val()
```

Or

```
$("#selector <b>></b> option:selected").text()
```

Above codes worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

This is what works

```
    var value= $('option:selected', $('#dropDownId')).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#dropDownId', function(){

            var value = $('select#dropDownId option:selected').text();

            //OR

            var value = $(this).val();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put like this.

```
$('[id$=dropDownId] option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method below to get the selected value on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#ddlid').on('change', function () {
                var value = $('#ddlid :selected').text();
                alert(value);`
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Normal Page loaded dropdowns

```
  $("#dropDownId").on('change',function(){
     var value=$(this).val();
     alert(value);
  });
```

for dynamically added options Make sure to keep the id unique

```
  $(document).on('change','#dropDownId',function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    alert(value)
  });
```

Comment: What if your dropdown option was marked as selected programmatically (like from an ajax request that populates a dropdown)?  If you try to get a .val(), you will get null for the value (even though inspecting the source will show you that the option is, indeed, selected)!  $("myDD option:selected").val() will yield undefined.

Comment: it is the fastest way to access an element which presents during the page load the $(document).on change will rescan the document once again to find the programmatically added elements I think for his question my answer is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one dropdown try:

HTML:

```
<select id="dropdown1" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value='...'>Option1
    <option value='...'>Option2
</select>
<select id="dropdown2" onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value='...'>Option1
    <option value='...'>Option2
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
    function myFunction(sel) {
        var selected = sel.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="SecondSelect">
       <option>5<option>
       <option>10<option>
       <option>20<option>
       <option>30<option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var value = $('#SecondSelect')[0].value;
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below line of code, we can get the dropdown list value. This will work:

```js
var getValue = document.getElementById("<%=ddlID.ClientID%>").value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#dropDownId").val('2');
var SelectedValue= $("#dropDownId option:selected").text();
$(".ParentClass .select-value").html(SelectedValue);


<p class="inline-large-label button-height ParentClass" >
     <label for="large-label-2" class="label">Country <span style="color: Red;">*</span><small></small></label>
     <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownId " CssClass="select" Width="200px">          
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
```