# How to find selected value of select in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Please advice, how to find selected value of a html select on its change.

code is below

```
$(".js-CellFirst").change(function () {
            alert($(this.find('option:selected')).text());<-- **trouble line**
});
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [To get selected value of a dropdown (<select>) element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value...

```
$(".js-CellFirst").val();
```

To get the text of the selected `option` element.

```
$(".js-CellFirst option:selected").text();
```

**However**, your specific issue is with your parenthesis, of which you have nested correctly. The correct use is...

```
alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
```

Comment: The jQuery library provides .val() for a reason: text() and others have some browser inconsistency.  The val method works for nearly any object in jQuery.

Comment: @Levi Browser inconsistency is a strong reason why jQuery exists. I don't understand what your comment is getting at...

Comment: @alex Don't use .text(), use .val().  Text only works on certain types of elements, but val works on nearly all.  That's all I'm saying.

Comment: @Levi To get an element's text node?

Comment: @alex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807867/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-functions-val-and-text

Comment: @alex, I'm not the best at explaining things sometimes.  That question sums it nicely.

Comment: @Levi I am using `text()` to get the text node of an `option` element, which should use `innerText` or `textContent` internally, and I have never had an issue with it.

Comment: @alex all I know is that the jQuery docs says 'The .text() method cannot be used on input elements. For input field text, use the .val() method.'  It seems to also be the case for other form elements, though   I can't find it said anywhere.

Comment: @Levi I'm not using it *on* an input element, per se, more a child element of an input.

Answer (score 2):

[Get selected value of a dropdown's item using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery)

Just use `alert($(this).val();` instead:

```
$(".js-CellFirst").change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
});
```