# jquery value get

Tags: jquery

```
<select id="placeSelect"  onchange="map_place_change();" > 
<option value="CN">China</option>
<option value="WORD">world</option>
</select>
```

when i select a value , how can i get it ? such , how can i get "CN" , how can i get "china" ?

thanks ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get selected text from dropdownlist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist) and [To get selected value of a dropdown (`<select>`) element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#placeSelect").val()

$("#placeSelect option:selected").text()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use following code:

```
function map_place_change(){
    var value = $(this).val(); // value = "CN"
    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();// China
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#placeSelect').change(function(){
  alert($('#placeSelect option:selected').html());
});
```

your function would be something like:

```
function map_place_change(){
    alert($('#placeSelect option:selected').html());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(‘#’).find(“input[CHECKED]“).val()
```