# Using jQuery to get a select box value with the selectedindex

Tags: jquery

Is it possible with jQuery to get the value of a select box item based on the selected index? I ask because what I actually need is the value of the items before and after the current selectedindex for next/previous buttons.  This is the code I tried but it did not work.

```
var my_value = $('#my_element_id').attr("selectedIndex").val();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [To get selected value of a dropdown (<select>) element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it (after my 3rd edit :-) )

It's quite verbose, but pretty easy to see what it's doing. I'm sure you can shorten it:

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/59SPw/

html:

```
<select id="my_element_id">
    <option>Alex</option>    
    <option selected="selected">IS</option>
    <option>Cool</option>
</select>
```

Js:

```
var selectedIndex = $('#my_element_id :selected').index();

if(selectedIndex  > -1)
{
    selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1; //index() is 0 based, nth-child is 1 based

    var prevIndex = selectedIndex - 1;
    var nextIndex = selectedIndex + 1;

    var prev = $('#my_element_id :nth-child(' + prevIndex  + ')').val();

    var next= $('#my_element_id :nth-child('+  nextIndex + ')').val();

    alert(prev || "no previous");
    alert(next || "no next");
}
```

Comment: Pants, I didn't read the question properly, one sec I'll edit it to get the next / previous.

Comment: Double pants, that doesn't work at all... one sec I'll write up an example.

Comment: Triple pants, that worked!  You're my jQuery hero.  Thanks man.

Comment: @CloudKiller Glad to be of service! I think i'm addicated to stackoverflow... :-)