# PHP: Getting values dynamically from a dropdown?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get selected option value: 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Connection refused!'.mysql_error());
    }
    $dbs = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
    echo "<select name=\"dbs_present\">";
    $i = 1;
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbs))
    {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">".$res['Database']."</option>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

I can be able to display databases present in mysql in a dropdown using the above code but i unable to get the option which is selected in the dropdown..
How can i get the selected option so that i can display tables present inside that selected database?!

Comment: Isn't it in `$_POST['dbs_present']` or `$_GET['dbs_present']`?

Comment: you need a form and submit to another page, from there you can read by using $_POST['dbs_present'];

Comment: PHP runs on the server side and the user interacts with the page in his browser, on the client. You have to send the data back to your server. That's what forms are for. Read about them in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php.

Comment: To do this dynamically (without submitting a form) you should either use javascript or jquery. Please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2780584/824495) if you are allowed to use JQUery.

Answer (score 0):

```
u can use this the execution time be less

echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$res['Database']."</option>";
```

Comment: And how does this gives us the selected item's value?

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
$selectOption = $_POST['dbs_present'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this if you submit on the same page.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Connection refused!'.mysql_error());
    }
    $dbs = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
    echo '<select name="dbs_present">';
    $i = 1;
    while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbs))
    {
        $selected_text = "";
        if(isset($_REQUEST['dbs_present']) && $_REQUEST['dbs_present']==$i)
        {
            $selected_text = " selected ";
        }  
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'" '.$selected_text.'>'.$res['Database'].'</option>';
        $i++;
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this **dynamically** *(without submitting a form)*, you should either use **JavaScript** or **jQUery**. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2780584/824495) if you are allowed to use [jQUery](http://jquery.com/).

**Using JQuery :**

Get the currently selected item's value :

```
$('#dbs_present').val();
```

---

**Using JavaScript :**

```
var value = document.getElementById("dbs_present").value;
```

To tell *your server* this value, you should either use an ajax call, or submit the form.

Comment: You're welcome, please upvote if you think this answer is useful, and accept it if this is the solution to your problem.