# How to get the value from drop downlist in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<optgroup label="Breeding" class="parent-option">
  <option class="child-option" value="Foal Out" disabled style="font-weight: bold; color: #555555 " selected="false">Foal Out</option>
  <option value="Breeding, Foal Out, General">&nbsp;&nbsp; General</option>
  <option value="Breeding, Foal Out, Report">&nbsp;&nbsp; Report</option>

 <option class="child-option" value="Gestation" disabled style="font-weight: bold; color: #555555 " selected="false">Gestation</option>
  <option value="Breeding, Gestation,l General">&nbsp;&nbsp; General</option>
  <option value="Breeding, Gestation, Report">&nbsp;&nbsp; Report</option>

<option  class="child-option" value="Mare" disabled style="font-weight: bold; color: #555555 " selected="false">Mare</option>
  <option value="Breeding, Mare, AI Cooled Semen">&nbsp;&nbsp; AI Cooled Semen</option>
  <option value="Breeding, Mare, AI Frozen Semen">&nbsp;&nbsp; AI Frozen Semen</option>
</optgroup>
```

How can I get the the value of nearest child-option class and nearest parent-option class value when any of the option is selected from drop down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To get selected value of a dropdown (<select>) element in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/to-get-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-select-element-in-jquery)

Comment: What do you mean by nearest? If i select `Report` in dropdown then what will be it's nearest? Will it be `Gestation` Or `Foal Out`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) method of jquery

```
$("select").change(function(){
   alert($("option:selected").prevAll(".child-option").val());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/101/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var $opt = $('option:selected', this),
        $parent = $opt.parent(),
        $child = $opt.prevAll('.child-option').addBack().first();
    console.log($parent.attr('label'))
    console.log($child.text())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AeMjM/)

Answer (score 0):

To get nearest `.child-option` to that of selected

```
  $("option:selected").prevAll(".child-option:first");
```

To get nearest `.parent-option` to that of selected

```
  $("option:selected").closest(".parent-option");
```

Comment: $("option:selected").closest(".parent-option");  This is not working. Another one working just fine