# How to select the DropDownList/Select that triggered the change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-controls

I'm new to JQuery and I noticed this line `$('#DivID [type=checkbox]')` and I was wondering if I can also find the select or option tags using the same method.

**Update:** I have a div that has more than more  tag, I'm trying to get the DropDownList/Select that it's value's just changed.

**Update2** I'm using InstaFilta a JQuery plugin that filter the content based on a customized attribute appended to my content tags. Below is a snippet for the function that do the same when working with CheckBoxes, and I'm trying to edit it to work with DropDownLists/Select controls.

```
var $ex10Checkboxes = $('#ex10 [type=checkbox]');

$ex10Checkboxes.on('change', function() {

    var checkedCategories = [];

    $ex10Checkboxes.each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            checkedCategories.push($(this).val());
        }
    });

    ex10.filterCategory(checkedCategories, true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would find the option tags as follows:

```
$("#DivID option")
```

Likewise the select tags:

```
$("#DivID select")
```

You can then iterate over the returned objects to inspect the individual elements:

```
var foo = $("#DivID option");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < foo.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(foo[i].val()); //or whatever
}
```

To find the selected element you could [check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery):

```
$("#DivID option:selected")
```

I would suggest checking out the JQuery page on Selectors [JQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)