# jquery dropdownlist give wrong result

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using following script but the problem is script 
is not working properly.Some time work and some time show wrong text.Instead of selected text.it Show me full text like this.

SELECT MINOR علوم الحاسب الآلي هندسة الطيران والفضاء والتكنولوجيا

```
<select class="cslMinor_Title" id="slMinor_Title">
    <option value="-1">Select Minor</option>
    <option value="201">علوم الحاسب الآلي</option>
    <option value="203">نظم المعلومات</option>
    <option value="299">تكنولوجيا المعلومات الأخرى</option>
</select>


 $('#slMinor_Title').on('change', function () 
 {
     alert($('.cslMinor_Title').find('option:selected').text());
 });
```

This is happen when i submit FORM through update panel and i am using this option in dialog box.
I want selected text not like below

SELECT MINOR علوم الحاسب الآلي هندسة الطيران والفضاء والتكنولوجيا
and also i tried many options like below

```
jQuery("#slMinor_Title option:selected").text()
```

But all are giving same result.Guide me what is the problem with code.

Comment: Try changing your `<option value="-1">Select Minor</option>` to `<option value="0">Select Minor</option>`. As I guess that might be the issue

Comment: I replaced with 0 but nothing happen

Comment: It seems to work fine. What do you mean this happens when you submit the form?

Comment: when i submit form it shows me full text like SELECT MINOR علوم الحاسب الآلي هندسة الطيران والفضاء والتكنولوجيا instead of selected option value text

Comment: Dude it works fine I tried it on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cbobtp8t/ may be if it is browser issue post what type of browser u are using and try it on fiddle urself too

Comment: @testtwes, please make a jsFiddle for us, as the same code is working for others

Comment: I am using firefox and asp.net c# as backend.So its impossible for me to create js fiddle.

Comment: @testtwes: I think you should check your code again, as suggested by `codehx` its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `val()`  function to get value.

```
jQuery("#slMinor_Title option:selected").val();
```

Mark it as answer if you think it is helpful for you.

Comment: this script not solving my problem

Comment: did you try that latest ansswer?

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery)

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```