# Getting value from a dropBox using Cherrypy in Python

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am new to Cherrypy, Kindly help me how can I get the selected value from dropdown using cherrypy in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the dropbox is a  element with id="dropDownId"; i assume the server call is done using jquery.

the value of the currently selected item is

```
$('#dropDownId').val();
```

the currently selected text:

```
$('#dropDownId :selected').text();
```

You can post it to the server with an ajax request:

```
    queryparams = $.param({     
                        "dropDownVal":$('#dropDownId').val(),
                        "email":$("#email").val(), 
                        "password":$("#password").val(), 
                    });

    $.ajax  ({
        url: '/login',
        type: "POST",
        data: queryparams,
    })
```

On the server side we have a cherrypy funcion, exposed to receive requests for the "login" page:

```
class mainPage():

@cherrypy.expose
def login(self,password=None,email=None,dropDownVal=None):

    self.password = password
    self.email = email.strip().lower()
    self.dropDownVal = dropDownVal

    cherrypy.log(self.dropDownVal)

    return "login ok"
```

It expects 3 optional parameters (email,password,dropDown), logs the "dropDownVal" and returns the string "ok" to the browser.

Comment: Credits to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery for the javascript part.