# icCube drop-down widget - How to get Selected Item?

Tags: javascript, iccube, iccube-reporting

I want to get selected items from iccube-dropdown-widget with javascript.  Drop-down-widget has Div-ID ‘icCubeDropDown’.

```
var t = window.document.getElementById(‘icCubeDropDown’);
```

doesn’t work, t is Null.
How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

`var text = $("#w8 select.icCubeDropDown").children("option").filter(":selected").text();` var text is empty. What is wrong?

Here is my report code:

[my report code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zo0v.png)

Comment: Show, please, how you declare you drop down widget?

Comment: It happens in the background of icCube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing class with id, 'icCubeDropDown' is a class. Id's in icCube are more like 'ic3-131'.

I'd be using jquery [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
var select = $("#ic3-131 select.icCubeDropDown")
```

this finds the element with id ic3-131 and a select descendant.

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, this get me closer to my solution. Pleas read my edited Question.

Comment: ana, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery and play a bit to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks! Now I figured out how I can get selected items by id, but there is another problem.  Div-Ids are dynamic and changes always, so my solution doesn’t work consistently. What options do I have to solve this problem?

Comment: you can add in the widget/box a class that is unique per id and use it for selection

Comment: Thank you! you helped me a lot :)