# How to get data sent from AJAX POST in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get POST data using `AJAX & JQUERY`

I have a bootstrap dropdown in which i show some values from database.
I want to pass the item i selected as POST to my PHP.

My dropdown is like this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php
      foreach($sites as $site)
      {
        echo "<li class='specialLink' id='".$site->site_key."'><a href='#'>".$site->site_key."</a></li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Now the my problem is when i echo the POST Values in PHP i get nothing, while if i alert the data from ajax then it shows me the correct value.

Also if i open my browser console in can see the values i select in **Network->XHR** tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
    var site = this.id;
    console.log(site);
    var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 

     //get value for throw to controller

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", //send with post 
        url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
        data: {site:site}, 
        success:function(data){ 

        },

    });
});
```

Trying to get Values like this in PHP:

```
 if(!empty($_POST))
    {
       //$site = $_POST['site'];

        echo $this->input->post('site');
       //$this->session->set_userdata('site', $site);
    }
```

In Console i can see the item selected like this:
[image]

```
Request URL:http://127.0.0.1/bizrtc/customer/dashboard/index
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
site:HT45-YT6T
```

Comment: @Rajan Can you show  what do you get in "console.log(site);"

Comment: @KetanSolanki i get the item i select from dropdown

Comment: can you try `echo $_POST['site];`? might be related to codeigniter's post sanitation, although unlikely...

Comment: i tried that @AlexTartan also i tried to echo echo $_REQUEST[]

Comment: Should i not be using something like this :   xhr.send();

Comment: i dont know what this might do but the examples i have seen usually send the data like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create a simple div:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Do a echo json_encode

```
if($_REQUEST['function'] == 'function_site')
    {
       $site = $_POST['site'];
       //$this->session->set_userdata('site', $site);
       $response['site'] = $site;

       echo json_encode($response);

    }
```

and append your ajax result to him:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", //send with post 
        url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
        data: {site:site, function:function_site},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){ 
           $("#test").html(data.site);
        },

    });
```

I dont have an enviroment to test for you right now, but You should see what you are echoing now.

Comment: if i add a div inside the li tag it will change the look of the nav bar?

Comment: @Rajan, no, put the div outside the li. You should see what you are echoing.

Comment: i get this php error Message: Undefined index: function

Comment: @Rajan are you passing the function parameter on ajax?

Comment: i just copies your code and pasted and tried then i got this error

Comment: Don't just copy/paste it, because i'm not testing the code, but try to learn the way to do it. Are you try replace the ajax call for you ajax (not for the all javascript!) and do the same with the php

Comment: i replaced the ajax call but did n't work, @daniel do u think this thing :xhr.send(); can help me?

Comment: @Rajan, can you see the font code of the page to see the javascript? Can be the url in the Ajax. Or try to remove the echo in the url parameter and just type the url of your page.

Comment: i get this i use your code {"site":null} with this Message: Undefined index: site

Comment: Are you defining the variable site?

Comment: No, as you see i just have done this in script var site = this.id; and in php i did this $response['site'] = $site;

       echo json_encode($response);

Comment: So you have to define it with the value from your li

Comment: So How do i do that?

Comment: Add an I'd to your drop-down, and get the value on javascript with $('#your_dropdown_id').val();

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery

Comment: as you see the code #speicallink is my id for the dropdown and i m pasing that to ajax

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your drop down code like this ,see if it works:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Your Sites <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <?php
      foreach($sites as $site)
      {
        echo "<li class='specialLink' data-id='".$site->site_key."' id='".$site->site_key."'><a href='#'>".$site->site_key."</a></li>";
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And Your JS code to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( ".specialLink" ).click(function() {
//        var site = this.id;
          var site = $(this).attr('data-id').val; 
        console.log(site);
        var url= "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>"; 

         //get value for throw to controller

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", //send with post 
            url: "<?php echo base_url('customer/dashboard/index') ?>", 
            data: {site:site}, 
            success:function(data){ 

            },

        });
    });
```

Comment: @Rajan try to alert  the variable "Site" ,I have changed the code.

Comment: ketan if i alert like this i get proper alert  var site = this.id;
        console.log(site);
        alert(site);

Comment: if i try your way i get undefined in alert