# HTML Select unable to get selected value data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, my current code is to hide options from the dropdown of selected items. The below code is working when the user selects the option it will hide the selected value in all the dropdowns. But I facing one issue which is when I want to get all the selected value from the dropbox box it will return a null value when the save button trigger. Anyone can help with this, I stuck in this issue long time :((?

[image]

Source Code: https://jsfiddle.net/8forcbg3/4/

```
$( ".firstname").on('change',function() {

            
 $(".firstname option").prop("disabled", false); //enable everything

            //collect the values from selected;
            var arr = $.map(
                        $(".firstname option:selected"), function (n) {
                            return n.value;
                        }
                    );

            //disable elements
            $(".firstname option").filter(function () {
                return $.inArray($(this).val(), arr) > -1; //if value is in the array of selected values
            }).prop("disabled", true);

            //re-enable elements
            $(".firstname option").filter(function () {
                return $.inArray($(this).val(), arr) == -1; //if value is not in the array of selected values
            }).prop("disabled",false);

            $(this).prop('disabled',false);//re-enable the current one //1
            $(this).show();//and show it //1
            $(this).prop('selected',true);//just to be sure re-select the option afterwards //1
           
        });
        
        
         $('.savebtn').on('click', function(){
         $('.cbb').each(function(index, item){
            var selectVal  = $(this).find('select').val();
                       
                        console.log(selectVal);
                        
                         });
         });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value of a dropdown's item using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution for your question is this:

```js
$('.savebtn').on('click', function(){
    $('.cbb').find('select option:selected').each(function(index, item){
        var selectVal = $(this).val();
        console.log(selectVal);
    });
});
```

You must use a selector `:selected` to get the current selected option.

Answer (score 3):

Here's [Get selected value of a dropdown's item using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780566/get-selected-value-of-a-dropdowns-item-using-jquery)
Get Selected value by like this,

```
 var selectVal  = $(this).find('select :selected').text();
```